# SET_NLS fails over Oracle ODP.net

Tags: c#, oracle, ado.net, odp.net

I try to execute the follwing statement from a c# program with ODP.NET:

```
string sql = "BEGIN dbms_session.set_nls('NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS','''.,'''); END;";
        using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection("Data Source=db;User Id=a;Password=b"))
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand(sql, connection))
            {
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            connection.Close();
        }
```

I retrieve the follwing error message:

*ORA-02074: cannot SET NLS in a distributed transaction*

I don't use any transaction in my code. Is the OracleConnection an implicit distributed transaction? If I add *enlist=false* to the connection string it works. But I don't know why.

Comment: Try to add DistribTX=0 to the connection. string see [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33659377/cannot-set-nls-in-a-distributed-transaction-error-using-ssis](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33659377/cannot-set-nls-in-a-distributed-transaction-error-using-ssis)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about C#, but are you sure you need the connection.Open() and connection.Close() statements? I would assume that the using statement takes care of that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't need distributed transactions in my environment, so I just solved this by appending `enlist=false` to my connection string. Hope it may be useful to someone.