# ORA-06512 : cannot set NLS in Distributed transactions

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I have an Oracle procedure containing this line:

```
ALTER SESSION SET nls_date_format = 'dd/mm/yyyy'
```

When trying to access the procedure from Coldfusion 10, I am getting an error message like

> Error executing database query 
>   [macromedia][Oracle JDBC Driver][oracle][ora-20001] error encountered -2074-ORA-06512 : cannot set nls in Distributed transactions.

If I comment out that line in the procedure, I am able to retrieve data from the procedure. FYI - the same procedure works in CF6 without commenting out the `ALTER SESSION ....` line.

Comment: (Shot in the dark...) The comments on [your other thread](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2275829) suggest it may not be supported. Any change if you use a different driver? Also, if it really is unsupported, and you do not need distributed transactions, for grins you might try [this suggestion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11221971/set-nls-fails-over-oracle-odp-net) of appending `enlist=false` to the DSN connection string.

Comment: ColdFusion does not use DSN connection strings.  Looking at the actual command, if the SP is used by ColdFusion only, it hardly seems necessary.  You can format dates in oracle with to_char or in ColdFusion with dateformat.

Comment: i will try with To_char option @Dan

Comment: *ColdFusion does not use DSN connection strings* @DanBracuk - Sure it does, under advanced settings. RE: *format dates in oracle with to_char or in ColdFusion with dateformat.* All depends on what is needed. For stored procedure input, it is best to pass in date objects instead of date strings. For display purposes, return date objects and use dateFormat() in the presentation layer.